# DocuSign REST API Creating a Non-Numeric RecipientId Causes Invalid Recipient ID Error When Adding Tabs

Tags: rest, docusignapi

I was able to add a recipient to an envelope with a recipientId that was the HASH of the recipient's email address (50a5ae9b6d8889c1fda3f140621b448b). However, I was not able to add tabs to that recipient. I was able to edit the recipient name and email address, so the system seems to be able to recognize the recipientId. It appears to be a problem with the recipientId in the URL since adding tabs is the only REST API call that uses the recipientId in the URL.

After more testing, I found that there is a limit of 32 characters to the length of the recipientId but you can still edit the recipient and assign a recipientId that is not valid (alphanumeric and/or greater than 32 characters).

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing different results, and seeing the system act as expected here.  First off, if I try to add a 32 digit number for the recipientId such as

```
12345678901234567890123456789012
```

I'm able to add the recipient just fine, then subsequently modify their tabs.  Next, if I try an alpha numeric string, such as (notice the z at the end)

```
1234567890123456789012345678901z
```

The system generates an error stating **INVALID_RECIPIENT_ID - A recipient ID is missing or invalid.**  I also get this error if I try a completely numeric number that is *greater than* 32 digits in length.

Please re-test and confirm your results, as this appears to be functioning as designed.

Comment: I was able to create a 32-digit recipient id which functioned normally and I was able to create a recipient id with a mix of numbers and letters but was then unable to add tabs to it. Based on an error message I received, it looks like recipient id can be numeric or a GUID. The latter makes me think there is some way to use a HASH of the email to generate a Recipient ID but I have been unable to figure this out. I tried an MD5 hash but that did not work.

Comment: When I tried the second 32 digit string posted above (the one ending in z) I got an error and was not able to add the recipient.  Are you saying that you do NOT get an error using such a string?

Comment: I do get an error trying to submit any recipient id that is greater than 32 characters long. However, I can save a recipient id that is a GUID or mix of letters and numbers. But, I can't add tabs to it when it is a GUID, only when it is numeric. I think there is a problem with the REST API in parsing the recipient id from the URL. That would explain the problems deleting recipients as well.

Comment: Hey guys, is it all good. i was having the problem too and saw your comments and tried out the GUID and it worked form me, this was my GUID - 9e304eb8-99d0-4cc1-be71-7ca479c16a58 . And i generated using this online tool - https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx. thanks for the help guys!